# Reference website to test IPv6 client to IPv4 server connectivity with NAT64 technology

Tags: networking, ipv6

Is there any website that is still using IPv4 address and can be connected using NAT64 technology from IPv6-Only client (browser on IPv6-Only device)?

If anybody knows could you please provide me the URL?

Thanks...

Comment: If your hosts are IPv6-only, then you need a NAT64 translator to connect to any IPv4-only site. It is your responsibility to translate, not the destination. There is nothing different about the IPv4 destination.

Answer (score 1):

I run a service for municipalities in the Netherlands to make their IPv4 website reachable over IPv6 using NAT64.

One example is https://www.arnhem.nl/

So this is an IPv4-only website reachable by IPv6-only clients through NAT64. Is that what you meant?

Comment: I was under the impression that NAT64 has to be deployed at server side. But from Ron Maupin comment I understood the concept . Both your answer and Ron Maupin comment helped me.